# Excel Drop Down List Auto-Select

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

See My spreadsheet here [My Spread Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNxHL.png), I have circled where the 3 drop down lists are.

I have recently started trying to do some very basic VBA in Excel. In my current spread sheet I have a table of work hours, which is filled in by selecting a date from a drop down list and then selecting the hours worked for each person from a drop down list per person, finally "set" is selected from a 3rd drop down list which results in the table being filled with the right time for the given date.

Bearing in mind I am new to this, what I want to know is if there is a way so that when a date is selected for the first drop down list, the drop down lists for each person will autoselect the time which is already in the table?

For example if the 26/10/2016 were selected in the first date drop down list, below person 1 would autoselect "02:25"from the drop downlist, person 2 would autoselecgt "03:00" from the drop down list, person 3 would select "OFF", person 4 "OFF" and finally person 5 would auto select "OFF" from the drop down list. See [SpreadSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC7Wu.png)

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks for any help you can give!

Dani

EDIT:

So I took the formula you provided and I wrote some very simple VBA anyway (as this is more of an academic project) so that when the date in the drop down list changes it updates the times. I have removed the drop down lists that were used for the changing the times. Once again, thank you for your help @user3598756

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("C4") Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        ActiveSheet.Range("C6").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX($G$4:$K$35,MATCH($C$4,$F$4:$F$35,0),MATCH(Left($B6,Len($B6)),$G$2:$K$2,0))"

        ActiveSheet.Range("C7").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX($G$4:$K$35,MATCH($C$4,$F$4:$F$35,0),MATCH(LEFT($B7,LEN($B7)),$G$2:$K$2,0))"

        ActiveSheet.Range("C8").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX($G$4:$K$35,MATCH($C$4,$F$4:$F$35,0),MATCH(LEFT($B8,LEN($B8)),$G$2:$K$2,0))"

        ActiveSheet.Range("C9").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX($G$4:$K$35,MATCH($C$4,$F$4:$F$35,0),MATCH(LEFT($B9,LEN($B9)),$G$2:$K$2,0))"

        ActiveSheet.Range("C10").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX($G$4:$K$35,MATCH  ($C$4,$F$4:$F$35,0),MATCH(LEFT($B10,LEN($B10)),$G$2:$K$2,0))"

Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need VBA

assuming:

- your table of work hours is in cells G4:K28
- your table of work hours "person" headers are in cells G2:K2
- your table of work "dates" are in cells F4:F28
- your first date drop down list is in cell C4
- your "person #" cells to write hours into are in cells C5:C9

then you can write the following formula in cell C5

```
=INDEX($G$4:$K$16,MATCH($C$4,$F$4:$F$16,0),MATCH(Left($B5,Len($B5)-1),$G$2:$K$2,0))
```

and drag it down to other cells

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Sorry my question was so convoluted!